# Can "Pulsus" be used to suggest the beating of a pulse from something other than the human body?

Tags: vocabulary

[Pulsus](https://www.latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries?t=sh20036) when used with *arterium* specifically references the beating of the arteries in a person. If I wanted to describe something inanimate as having a pulse, would it make sense to an ancient Roman to use *pulsus* with another noun? I'm not sure if they would get the meaning in the way we do in English where it retains an allusion to a heartbeat, or if they'd just see it more as a *beating of some thing*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but just be careful that *pulsus* can mean any sort of beat or rhythm. You'll see it [frequently with *remorum*](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23pulsu+%7E+remorum) to mean the rhythm of the oars of a ship, for example.

To make it clear you intend to compare the *pulsus* of some inanimate object to a heartbeat, I would go a little more on the descriptive side and bring in an actual comparison. For an example, you could see something like *pulsus montis quasi intus in eo venae sunt.*

I know you've been using Latin as song titles, and in that case the *pulsus montis* would be only as ambiguous as the English, that yes it could mean heartbeat, but considering mountains don't have hearts, it *might* mean something else until it is clarified. But that's often the case with song titles, isn't it?

Comment: Awesome - thank you! In my usage the ambiguity is definitely totally fine and is poetic in its own way (in my opinion, anyway).